How to change the log timestamp format in Temporal Workflow CLI?
I'm using the Temporal Workflow CLI version 1.1.1
I'm starting my Temporal server like this:
temporal server start-dev --ui-port <MY PORT NUMBER> --db-filename myfile.db

When I execute a workflow I see a log messages that look like this:

time=2024-11-03T05:22:15.262 level=WARN msg="Failed to poll for task." service=worker Namespace=temporal-system TaskQueue=temporal-sys-per-ns-tq WorkerID=server-worker@54622@74a6cde0c483@temporal-system WorkerType=WorkflowWorker Error="worker stopping"

The content of the log message above is irrelevant. However, I want to change the format of the timestamp.
The timestamp shown above is in my local time (US Eastern). I want it to appear in UTC with a Z at the end. I also want to control how many decimal places the fractional seconds are shown in. How can I make that change?
This doc indicates that I should use the --time-format command line switch. However the only options available are relative, iso & raw. I tried all three and there was no visible change to the output format.

Did you set the time zone to 'utc'?

No. I was unable to do it. Please show me exactly how I would do that with the command line. Please include the actual.command.

Some like is answered Temporarily change timezone to display date/time:  TZ=UTC  temporal server start-dev --ui-port <MY PORT NUMBER> --db-filename myfile.db

I meant via their command line. I haven't tried it, I just saw it was an option when I clicked on your CLI documentation link

I did a quick test, it seems that logging is always done in the timezone that is set when starting temporal.  By specifying TZ=UTC on the command-line before starting it changes only for that process (on Linux, not on Windows...)

Try to start the server with:

TZ=UTC temporal server start-dev --ui-port <MY_PORT_NUMBER>
--db-filename myfile.db

As the timezone we mention while starting the server is used so this sets logs to UTC and will ensure timestamps are shown in UTC. However, it doesn’t control fractional seconds or the exact format.
Alternate approach by manually Post-Process Logs: If fine-grained formatting (like controlling fractional seconds) is required then post logs processing can be done on the files.
Just found out that temporal does not allow to control the time in fractions or in decimals. You may request for such feature -> https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+

Are you sure? This looked promising. But when I tried it, it says there is no such flag --config. There is --env-file, however when I gave it the yaml file you suggested, it gave the error failed unmarshalling env YAML: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Just checked by quick testing that it does not allow to get the fractions or decimals in timeframes. You can only set the TZ to UTC while starting the server and then maybe post process the files as per your format. Try using awk if this helps, let me know.
TZ=UTC temporal server start-dev --ui-port <MY_PORT_NUMBER> --db-filename myfile.db | awk '{gsub(/T/, " "); gsub(/Z/, ""); print $0}'

Temporal uses the Go slog package with two handlers - json and text.
Setting log-format to json sets the time format in the log such that the timezone offset is displayed. However there does not seem to be an option to perform automatic timezone conversion. It displays the current system time with additional timezone information.
temporal server start-dev --log-format json

Sample log output given below when the system timezone is UTC.
{"time":"2024-11-24T22:18:19.4708375Z","level":"WARN","msg":"Failed to poll for task.","service":"worker","Namespace":"temporal-system",...}

Sample log output given below when the system timezone is UTC+5:30.
{"time":"2024-11-25T03:58:52.9650575+05:30","level":"WARN","msg":"Failed to poll for task.","service":"worker","Namespace":"temporal-system",...}


Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?, but this is the same for answers. When you post a picture which only contains text, then ask yourself if it s REALLY needed to post a picture.  Also this does not seem to be an answer to the question?

Removed the image as suggested. When there is no obvious solution to do automatic conversion of timezone, at least the next best option is to display the timezone so that logs can be transported anywhere and analyzed.
